# Set index page node js

Tags: node.js

How do you index.php or index.html using node, so when you go to blahblah.com your node site loads up.

If have the app.js right, now the browser just needs to know where to find the index file

```
/*
* Module dependencies
*/
var express = require('express')
, stylus = require('stylus')
, nib = require('nib')

var logger = require('morgan')
var app = express()
function compile(str, path) {
return stylus(str)
.set('filename', path)
.use(nib())
}
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views')
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(stylus.middleware(
 { src: __dirname + '/public'
, compile: compile
}
))
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.render('index',{title : 'CheckMe',subheader:'health and fitness for        kids',logo:'<img src="images/logo.png" alt="">'})
})
app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no index.html file in Express. Using a single forward slash as your location, like you did with `app.get('/', function (req, res) {})` defines your root page. Going to `localhost:3000` without any filename should work for you.

Comment: tried that, I want to turn the site live (not local host) so when you go to blahblah.com it renders the index.jade file

Comment: No. Node is a totally different paradigm than what you're used to. Put the file wherever you want and run `node filename.js`.

Comment: To do that safely you need to put it behind a reverse proxy. I recommend and use [nginx](http://nginx.org/), but there are other options available. Technically you could just run it as root and bind to port 80, but that's a security risk.

Answer (score 0):

Had to change the virtual host proxy settings

```
<VirtualHost 109.74.199.47:80>
ServerAdmin davy.brion@thatextramile.be
ServerName thatextramile.be
ServerAlias www.thatextramile.be

ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location />
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3000/
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache